# Sharepoint 2013: Approval workflow option is not dispalyed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to a configure the Sharepoint 2010- Approval workflow to the list. I have activated the "Workflow" under site collection features. After enabling, under the "Add a workflow" in list > workflow setting, the template name is not displayed. Kindly help me to enable this approval workflow on Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to Microsoft workflow interruption. Check the global admin site in case if you received the message from Microsoft specifying the same.